# output keyword in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I would like to know what the keyword `output` means in OCaml.

I looked at the documentation which says :

```
val output : out_channel -> bytes -> int -> int -> unit

output oc buf pos len writes len characters from byte sequence buf, starting at offset pos, to the given output channel oc. Raise Invalid_argument "output" if pos and len do not designate a valid range of buf.
```

The problem is that I don't understand at all what of all this mean.

It would be very nice if you could provide a simple example of code where the keyword output is used.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no keyword `output`. There is only a *function* named output that's in the `Pervasives` module.

The purpose of `output` is to write some bytes to an output channel.

If you choose printable bytes, and if your output channel is the standard output, you can see the result in a small test:

```
# let mybytes = Bytes.of_string "hello\n";;
val mybytes : bytes = Bytes.of_string "hello\n"
# output stdout mybytes 0 6;;
hello
- : unit = ()
#
```

To show that `output` is just an identifier (i.e., a name) and not a keyword, note that you can define your own value named `output`:

```
# let output = 3010;;
val output : int = 3010
#
```

This is not the case with real keywords such as `then`:

```
# let then = 3010;;
Error: Syntax error
#
```